# ga('set', 'userId', '1234') doesn't send anything

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I try to use Analytics' user authentication in a asynchronous way. I followed [this doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#handling_authentication_after_pageload), so I have these two codes:

**In my HTML code, in  section**

```html
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-36705395-2', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
    ga('require', 'linker');
    ga('linker:autoLink', ['my.website.com'] );

    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

**And in my external JS, executed after pageload**

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://my.website.com/api/check_key?cid=' + cid,
    type: 'GET',
    accepts: {
        json: 'application/json'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('send userID to GA ('+ cid +')');
        ga('set', 'userId', cid);
    }
});
```

The problem: *ga('set', 'userId', cid);* doesn't send anything to GA, even though I have a trace in my console. There is no XHR call to GA.

When I switch GA to debug mode, I have this trace :

> Running command: ga("set", "userId", "123")

Did I miss something? Do *ga('set'...)* need something else to send data?

Thanks.

Comment: The data is sent when you send the pageview, so you need to make sure the userId is set before the pageview is sent.

Comment: @DavidHammond I can't because the userId is fetched in JS, after pageload, and I can't wait for the pageload to send a pageview. I followed this official Google Doc "[handling authentication after pageload](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#handling_authentication_after_pageload)".

Comment: That's one misleading bit of documentation. Yes, this adds the userid to the tracker, but you still need an interaction hit to send it.

Comment: Ah, okay. But I don't think the "set" function ever sends data. According to the doc, it should use session unification to associate the user id to the original hit, but I think it requires subsequent hits to send the data (maybe track a login event?).

Comment: That's what I meant (i.e. misleading on the part of Google, not you), "set" calls never send anything. They set the value for a field in a tracker permanently (i.e. for all requests that follow the set call), but do not do any requests themselves. Unless you send a hit after the set it will not do anything.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Looks like you're right. When it's previously defined, userId is associated with a new 'send' method (I tried with an event). But the automatic session unification with the "pageview" hit doesn't seem to work: in Analytics, the user has events, but no pageview..

Comment: @EikePierstorff yep, your reply just hadn't shown up for me yet when I posted mine

Comment: @DavidHammond, will you do  the honours and make this into an answer then ?

Answer (score 1):

The data is only sent to analytics when you use the 'send' command, so you need to record a pageview, an event, or a social interaction *after* the userid is set. Google's documentation for handling authentication after pageload is misleading because it fails to mention this.

In this case, recording a login event might make sense.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'account', 'login');
```